# During COVID, which Schengen Zone countries can be entered through non-Schengen corridor countries, without quarantine? (April 2021)

Tags: schengen, covid-19

As a resident of Ukraine (US passport holder), I'd like to know which Schengen Zone countries can be entered (I'd like to avoid the possible war in Ukraine, I assume border guards would currently look at my reason for entry as "for tourism purposes") without requiring quarantine time, when entered from a corridor country.

For example, Malta lists that travelers from Turkey can enter, assuming they've been in Turkey for the past 14 days.

So one could visit Turkey for 14 days, then visit Malta, then presumably visit other Schengen Zone countries from there.

I'd like to know if there are other similar "corridor countries" options available to enter the Schengen Zone, that allow bypassing quarantine time (COVID tests are no problem).

Comment: I continue to wonder why people are so keen to try to travel all over the place just for the fun of it in the middle of a global pandemic. I must be living on a different planet. On mine that pandemic has already killed 3 million people, and shows no signs of slowing down. In my country we’re back in lockdown and travel is forbidden.

Comment: Note that many countries' quarantine policies are based on countries you've been to in the past 14/10/7 days (usually coinciding with the quarantine time required). Entering from a Schengen country alone does not guarantee that you won't be subject to quarantine obligations.

Comment: Also, Schengen countries can impose quarantine requirement on other Schengen countries, Malta itself is also on the list of several Schengen countries as a high-risk zone requiring quarantine.

Comment: @jcaron - Ukraine is possibly not the safest place to be right now, and not because of anything COVID-related.

Comment: @simonatrcl Possibly not, but OP specifically says "for tourism purposes" and evidently would like to visit several countries, not just move to a safer location. If that was the plan it would be a very different question and it would elicit a very different reaction.

Comment: @jcaron Leaving Ukraine for safety is the #1 reason for wanting to enter an EU country, but you can't enter an EU country if you don't have a residency permit, in most cases. Since a war hasn't started (yet), I think the border guards would view my reason for entry as "tourism".

Comment: @AaronAsh you have a US passport, you can enter any EU country nearly as you like, and in some EU countries you are even allowed to stay without limit. And if you are trying to move for safety reasons, a few days in quarantine are probably the last of your concerns. Since many if not most countries are in lockdown anyway, quarantine or lockdown does not change things much...

Comment: While I haven't traveled since last year, there are many people who do and stay safe. This the right protocols, you can be safe pretty much anywhere. Otherwise, all hospital workers would be dead. Not travelling though is driving many people insane, especially since some of us can't leave the house past 8PM! We can leave the country though but unfortunately coming back is close to impossible, so I'm holding off until it becomes easier. Plus, I have vouchers from 2 cancelled family trips that are going to expire soon which amounts to several thousands for loss if we cannot recover or delay them

Comment: @jcaron "you can enter any EU country nearly as you like" not during covid, you must have a residency permit or work visa. You haven't been enjoying the peace and quiet from lack of tourists? ;)

Comment: @Itai absolutely. I've travelled within Ukraine the past year, it's quite easy to avoid people and get out in nature. You still have to go to local grocery stores, but it's really no more risk than the one back where you live. I believe I've already had covid as well, so minimal risk for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.